# How to select column across data frame in a list in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

After being convinced that it's best practice to use list to manage multiple data frames in R, I decided to put all my data frames that have the same column names into list.

sample list:

```
#create sample df
df_1 <- data.frame(item = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                   measure = c(1,2,3)
                   )
df_2 <- data.frame(item = c("x", "y", "z"), 
                   measure = c(4,5,6)
                   )

#use names as my df has names
data_list <- list(df_1 = df_1, df_2 = df_2)
```

I wanted to do the same operation across these data frames but I did not want them to be combined as one data frame as later on I'll need to save each into separate output.

Then it become a nightmare because I did not know how to manipulate column across all data frame inside a list.

While we can select a specific element and also the specific df in a list, how do we select by column name?

Taking an example, I need to change the value in the `item` column as Upper Case. In a data frame I'll do

```
df_1 <- df_1 %>% mutate(item = toupper(item))
```

I am still learning to write function and using the apply family in R. For this simple task I believe I can just use the existing function inside lapply like this

```
data_list = lapply(x, toupper)
```

The question is what is x in here? Is there a way to subset by column? Like `data_list$df_1` or `data_list[1]` can give me the whole df_1.

I hope I can use lapply and function to do column by column approach across data frame in a list.

Comment: `lapply(data_list, transform, item = toupper(item))`

Comment: woah, that's easy! I have never used transform before. I guess I can use that for other column operation as well?

Comment: You can indeed, e.g., `lapply(data_list, transform, item = toupper(item), csum = cumsum(measure))`.

Comment: Brilliant! So that's like the equivalent of `mutate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use `map` from `purrr`. So, if you have already written what you want to do for one dataframe in your list, then you can put it in as a function into `map`. You use `.x` rather than specifying the specific dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)

map(data_list, ~ .x %>%
      mutate(item = toupper(item)))
```

**Output**

```
$df_1
  item measure
1    A       1
2    B       2
3    C       3

$df_2
  item measure
1    X       4
2    Y       5
3    Z       6
```